# Iron Route - Server Side, access this.params from onBeforeAction()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I need to serve some REST API Endpoints from my meteor application.
Endpoints must be accessible on the server side, so I'm using Iron router for server side routing.
All works great, but now I need access to the `this.params` for permission checking.

My current route:

```js
Router.route('myServerRoute', {
    where: "server",
    path: '/api/v1/doit/:partner',
    onBeforeAction: function(req, res, next) {
        API.beforeAction(req, res, next, ['admin','API']);
    }
})
```

The **`API.beforeAction`** is a function I'm using to validate the user token (This token is in one of the headers)
This function check **if the token is valid and if that user have one of the roles** from the 4th parameter.

The `:partner` is the name of the partner that use the API.

Let say that `:partner` is `'store1'` (`/api/v1/doit/store1`)
I want to verify that **only users that have the `store1` role** will be able to access the `/api/v1/doit/store1` URL
So I want to pass the value of the `:partner` parameter to the `API.beforeAction` function

On the `onBeforeAction` function, **I don't have access to the** `this.params` (it is empty)
Some suggested to access the params using `Router.current()`
But this is a **client call**, and it is not available server side.

I can use `req.url`, parse it and get the partner name. but I don't like to do the parsing myself when I know that Iron Route already parsed this URL

*Any suggestions how to get the URL parameters inside the `onBeforeAction`?*

Comment: Weird, the [iron router guide section on hooks](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#using-hooks says "all properties available in the route function are also available here such as this.params"

Comment: @MichelFloyd, Yes, I thought so too...   
I tried to print it [console.log("params:",JSON.stringify(this.params, null, 2));]  But it just print out an empty array.    
I suspect that "this.params" is available only on client side routing.

Comment: Oh ya, server side. Could you put your role checking at the front of the route action instead?

Comment: @MichelFloyd, Yes I can. few things I don't like about it: Some endpoints have .post, .get, .put and .delete actions... This mean that I will have to duplicate the call to the my new "globalValidatePermission" function for each Endpoint type and not only once per route.   - Also, from security perspective, I prefer the user without permission will not even start to run the actual Endpoint code. I wan't to catch it before. as soon as possible

Comment: Then I think you're stuck at parsing `req.url`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do permission checking in your onBeforeAction. I implemented my API with Iron Router.
In the example bellow I handle a get request with an API key and return informations or error code.

```
Router.route('/api/thing/:apikey', { where: 'server' })
.get(function getThing () {
    if (typeof this.params.apikey === 'undefined' || this.params.apikey.length != 16 || !Userprofile.findOne({ apiKey: this.params.apikey })) {
        this.response.statusCode = 403;
        return this.response.end('Not authorized');
    }
    const things = Thing.find({ owner: Userprofile.findOne({ apiKey: this.params.apikey }).owner }).fetch();
    if (things.length > 0) {
        this.response.statusCode = 200;
        return this.response.end(JSON.stringify(things));
    } else {
        this.response.statusCode = 200;
        return this.response.end('No things found');
    }
});
```

Comment: For some of my API endpoints, I have POST, GET, PUT and DELETE...
To get the permission checking 4 times in 4 different function, will invite mistakes. 
Another thing is that I'm using the onBeforeAction for logging and alerting. this way all API request get the same type of logging, and there is only one place to change if I need to switch log supplier